# Why model cannot access another model using provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, state-management, flutter-provider

I want do this (not possible):

```
class Model1 extends ChangeNotifier {
...
  final List<Item> items = [];
}


class Model2 extends ChangeNotifier {

void performOperation() {
//Access items from Model1 here
final newItems = Provider.of<Model1>(context).items,
...
}


}
```

It seem [suggestion is use `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798046/how-to-pass-data-from-one-provider-model-to-another/56798205#56798205)
But this seem very inefficient. Why I must create another layer with `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` if I am not yet use this value in UI? I just want mix `Model1` and `Model2` for business logic here.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

One model can't access another model using provider because models are not widgets, they know nothing about providers and contexts.
If you don't want to use `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`, you might extract shared logic to separate class or method and reuse it inside models.

Comment: This is a feature `provider` can add?

Comment: No  it's not about provider. Provider is a way to connect widgets and data, but not business logic organization

Comment: Thanks for reply! How I can organize business logic better?